# DevExpress XAF Cascading Lookup List Views

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf, xpo

I have created DevExpress XAF Blazor application.
I have four tables(pages)
The first one is **Category** related by a one-to-many with **AssignedContractorCategory** table
-oid string
-Title string

```cs
private string _Title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Title), ref _Title, value); }
}

[DevExpress.Xpo.Association("Category-AssignedContractorCategory")]
public XPCollection<AssignedContractorCategory> AssignedContractorCategory
{
    get
    {
        return GetCollection<AssignedContractorCategory>(nameof(AssignedContractorCategory));
    }
}
```

The second one is **Contractor** related by a one-to-many with **AssignedContractorCategory** table
-oid string
-Title string

```cs
private string _Title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Title), ref _Title, value); }
}

[DevExpress.Xpo.Association("Contractor-AssignedContractorCategory")]
public XPCollection<AssignedContractorCategory> AssignedContractorCategory
{
    get
    {
        return GetCollection<AssignedContractorCategory>(nameof(AssignedContractorCategory));
    }
}
```

The third one is **AssignedContractorCategory** related by a one-to-many with **Bill** table
-oid string
-FKCategory string
-FKContractor string

```cs
private Category _Category;
[Association("Category-AssignedContractorCategory")]
public Category Category
{
    get { return _Category; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Category), ref _Category, value); }
}

private Contractor _Contractor;
[Association("Contractor-AssignedContractorCategory")]
public Contractor Contractor
{
    get { return _Contractor; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Contractor), ref _Contractor, value); }
}
```

The fourth one is **Bill**
-oid string
-FKAssignedContractorCategory string
-Amount double

```cs
private Category _Category;
public Category Category
{
    get { return _Category; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Category), ref _Category, value); }
}

private Contractor _Contractor;
public Contractor Contractor
{
    get { return _Contractor; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Contractor), ref _Contractor, value); }
}

private double _Amount;
public double Amount
{
    get { return _Amount; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Amount), ref _Amount, value); }
}
```

On Bill page I want to show :
Category (Lookup List Views) and after I chose one category it shows only Contractor (Lookup List Views) that are related on table **AssignedContractorCategory**
Please note that I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** On your `Bill` class, decorate the `Category`-property with the `ImmediatePostData` attribute. It will ensure that the setter will get called immediately after every change on the UI:

```
[ImmediatePostData]
public Category Category
```

**Step 2:** On the `Bill` class, add the `DataSourceProperty`-attribute to your `Contractor` property, and then implement a corresponding property which always returns the correct selection of Contractors. Note that I decorate the new `ContractorSelection`-property with `[Browsable(false)]` so that it's completely invisible on the XAF UI:

```
private Contractor _Contractor;
[DataSourceProperty(nameof(ContractorSelection))]
public Contractor Contractor
{
    get { return _Contractor; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Contractor), ref _Contractor, value); }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public IList<Contractor> ContractorSelection
{
    get
    {
       return Category?.AssignedContractorCategory.Select(i => i.Contractor).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** The problem now is that XAF does not automatically update its internal cache of the ContractorSelection-collection when you change the `Category`. For this to work, you need to change the setter of your `Category`-property and tell XAF than the `Contractor` property has also changed:

```
[ImmediatePostData]
public Category Category
{
    get { return _Category; }
    set 
    { 
        SetPropertyValue(nameof(Category), ref _Category, value);
        if (!IsLoading)
        {
            OnChanged(nameof(Contractor));
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this, and it works fine in XAF Blazor.

---

**Alternative method:**

If you prefer your objects to be filtered by the DB (ideal if you have a large collection of contractors), you can use the `DataSourceCriteria`-attribute instead, and then remove the `ContractorSelection`-property from my initial solution. All the other code remains the same:

```
private Contractor _Contractor;
[DataSourceCriteria("AssignedContractorCategory[Category = '@This.Category'].Count > 0")]
public Contractor Contractor
{
    get { return _Contractor; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Contractor), ref _Contractor, value); }
}
```

**Additional Info:**

- We have not defined what XAF should display when no category is selected. Check out the XAF documentation of the `DataSourceProperty`-attribute on how you can specify the appropriate behavior in case the datasource is null.
- You may also want to use the `Category`-setter to enforce other constraints, such as setting the `Contractor` to null in case the currently selected `Contractor` is not part of the selected category. The more interdependent properties you have, the more complex this gets.
- If your `AssignedContractorCategory` class is only used as a pure link between `Contractor` and `Category` (without additional properties), then you may want to consider using XPO's integrated [many-to-many associations](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112719/getting-started/in-depth-tutorial-winforms-aspnet/business-model-design/business-model-design-with-xpo/set-a-many-to-many-relationship-xpo)